# Android Studio editor not opening

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android studio, already have jdk 1.8 but when i click on finish during the creation of new project(Customize the Activity)  nothing happens, just nothing, what could be the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate  your problem and provide relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and restart your computer. Your computer probably needs a restart to fully complete the java installation. You will face this when installing a lot of programming languages. Plus restarting always fixes a lot of things so it couldn't hurt to try.